# Trying to fix a leaky faucet, structure was not I expected after removing the knobs

Tags: plumbing, bathroom, sink

My faucet has been dripping very slightly, so I decided to try fixing it. I watched a couple of videos, and it seemed like the task would be fairly easy.

I removed the top of my handles, and what I found was unlike any of the videos I have seen Here is a picture.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/KAVYC.jpg

The base around it is fairly stuck, and there isn't any kind of valve that I can remove from the top. I did take this picture of the bottom, though.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/NY573.jpg

Does anybody have any advice? The base of the handle feels like it is stuck to the counter. Do I have to remove it? Do I need to remove something from below the counter in order to fix this type of faucet?

Comment: That chrome base must come off somehow.  Feel the back for a set screw that holds it in place.  If you can turn the base to loosen with the help of a rubber gripper, you may need to removed that valve from the sink to further inspect it and see how it comes apart.

Comment: Thanks. There are no screws on the back, and the base does not seem to want to turn. Somebody on another website suggested prying it off with a screwdriver. I just tried removing it on the other sink in the bathroom (rarely used), and it was stuck there too. It almost looks like the person who installed it fastened it to the counter with some adhesive.

Comment: Can you determine the brand? If so, you can then look for exploded diagram on the manufacturer's site. I did a little searching, and Grohe has models that look a little (but not exactly) like that, and in theirs that chrome piece is a cap that pries off. It also appears that you could shut off the water, disconnect it underneath the sink, and lift the whole assembly up a bit to see how that top part comes apart.

Comment: They would have used caulk or plumbers putty, so could be kinda stuck.  I'd take it off and look if no one else happens to know that particular faucet.

Comment: There is no branding at all. This is what the assembled faucet looks like,
http://imgur.com/3SFAske

And this is what the base of the metal cap looks like, http://imgur.com/VkruxZw

I'll see if I can pry it off. I can't believe they would do that.

Comment: Don't pry it off. It unscrews counter clockwise. Use a padded wrench.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The base in the first photo will unscrew (counterclockwise). It will have to be removed in order to free the faucet base so it can drop through to the bottom. Check the base first for a recessed (set) screw that may keep it from loosening. Set screw can be loosened with a hex or slot driver.  The faucet base may not unscrew easily. In which case you should use either an  adjustable pair of pliers, pipe wrench or vise grip pliers. To prevent damaging the surface of the chrome base you can: wrap the jaws of the pliers with duct tape, wrap a rag around the base or do both.

Comment: Gotcha. I'll give this a shot, but it's incredibly difficult to grip with pliers or a wrench and a towel because it has no flat surfaces and the conic shape causes vice grips to shoot up off of the top. Thanks.

Comment: It's really stuck on there, and I can't get any kind of tool to grip it because of the shape. It looks like there might be some kind of buildup in there (hard to tell in the pic), so I might try using something to break down deposits to see if that loosens it. Some heat might also work.

Comment: Try gripping with long handled pliers at the base (very bottom) or mid-span (center).  Protect the porcelain when gripping at the bottom. Once you have it gripped, slowly exert force. Continue increasing torque and be alert that the jaws don't slip. The more force you apply to unscrew it you should increase your grip on the faucet base to prevent pliers from slipping. If pliers are hard to use switch to pipe wrench. The jaws are self-locking and won't slip as easy.

Comment: If you decide to loosen with heat use a heat gun not a torch.

Comment: You can also loosen the retaining nut on the underside of the sink. The base won't fully come away, but maybe you will have a better view of the underside of the base.

Comment: Consider using a [strap wrench](http://www.homedepot.com/p/Husky-8-in-Strap-Wrench-009-193-HKY/202277618). It may be able to grab the bottom edge without damaging the faucet or sink.

Comment: Stopped by ace hardware and the guys helped me out. They had a fairly expensive strap wrench as well as a couple that might not fit, so I actually just grabbed this rubber pad that the guy recommended. It gave me some grip on the slippery surface of the escutcheon, and I was able to get it off with some back and forth. Thanks! http://imgur.com/EYbVAnr

Answer (score 0):

This is commonly referred to as a *widespread* lavatory faucet. Follow @ojait instructions to remove the upper escutcheon and you should then be able to remove and repair the actual valve.

There is no need to loosen or remove the faucet valve bodies, except for your's are rotated such that you have some pretty lame kinks in that flex hose. if you are cool with that then do not disturb the valve body itself, just service from above.

Answer (score 0):

Underneath I see a black plastic nut to clamp the handles to the sink. You will need to loosen those so that you can lift the handles up and possibly expose the method of removing the cap.